# Node-mysql with mariadb

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I already use mariadb as a mysql server. However, I'm not sure using a node package designed for mysql is a good idea to use for mariadb.

There are actually two node packages:

- For [mscdex/node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql)
- For [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

I currently use mysql, since it seems pretty mature and maintained.
It also seems to work well with mariadb on my side.

Are there any restrictions/incompatibilities/security issues to use [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) over [mscdex/node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql) for a mariadb server?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter which you use. MariaDB is backwards compatible with MySQL. You could even connect to MySQL with node-mariasql if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. Taking a look at your package sources, I really like the idea to rely on the dynamic library (libmariadbclient). I may finally prefer node-mariasql.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i am currently working on project with Maria DB and i am using node-mysql for production. It works really well for me. Reason of not using node-mariadb is the number of ratings and maturity of package.

Answer (score 2):

I used `mariasql` in the past.  It didn't cast fields to their proper JS type.  Everything came back as a string (even integers).  I'm going to try out the `mysql` driver.  Seems weird that I have to use a different connection for each query if I want to do it in parallel.  Seems like that should be abstracted for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code my be helpfull for xampp mysql connection by using NodeJS

```
  var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : '<database name>'
    }); 
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    else{
        console.log("database has been connected");
    }
    });
    var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM <table name>'; 
    connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        for (var i in rows) {
            console.log('filesname: ', rows[i].fieldname);
        }
    }); 
    connection.end();
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

My impression of node-mariasql is that it is immature in terms of supporting all database operations (especially prepared insert operations are lackluster atm) and also documentation is poor. I'd suggest using node-mysql for production applications.